# Unable to understand ALTER TABLE statement conflict

Tags: ef-core-2.2

I am unable to understand why this is causing issue here.

This issue could be because there is no matching data in tables, but i am running migrations on a new development environment which has no data seeded. This migration is in the mid of migrations. There are few migrations before it which execute correctly.

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Auctions_AuctionVariants_AuctionItemVariantID". The conflict
>   occurred in database "Lelaamghar", table "dbo.AuctionVariants", column
>   'ID'.

```
 migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Auctions_AuctionVariants_AuctionItemVariantID",
                table: "Auctions",
                column: "AuctionItemVariantID",
                principalTable: "AuctionVariants",
                principalColumn: "ID",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
```

I am using EF Core 2.2

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from this action? You can see the failed command by running `Update-Database` command with `-verbose` option.

Comment: @IvanStoev ok i have updated my question please check

Comment: Ok, it is from aforementioned action. I see seeding the `AuctionVariants` at the top (from  `HasData`?), now are we sure there is no such seeding for `Auctions` (so the table actually has records with no matching data)?

Comment: @IvanStoev ok the problem was, in there somewhere i was inserting data. I don't know how migration was properly created in the first place. I removed migration with data insert statements and its working fine now.

should I not include data in migrations?